# How to host an Apache Server on a Whonix box?

Tags: whonix, server

Is it possible to host an Apache Server (Wamp/Lamp)on  a Whonix box?

Just share the content using the Whonix box IP address?

Comment: https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Onion_Services

Comment: https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Hosting_Location_Hidden_Services